# search japanese characters (utf-8 encoded ) using Sqlite FTS 

Tags: sqlite, utf-8, full-text-search

It seems that Sqlite FTS don't support searching Japanese characters according to my experiments , and discussion [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414102).

```
#select * from tblEvent_shortdes where short_des MATCH   'ＢＳジャパンの見どころ' 
#return nothing
select * from tblEvent_shortdes where short_des MATCH  'パンの見'
```

Customize tokenizer in FTS seems to be the way to accomplish this but I did not found any promising open sourced tokenizer for Japanese. Will ICU tokenizer do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at [ChaSen](http://chasen-legacy.sourceforge.jp/) and [MeCab](http://mecab.sourceforge.net/).  It has been several years since I used either - and it looks as though neither has been updated recently - but both proved adequate at Japanese tokenization.